# Tomcat doesn't allow PUT request

Tags: tomcat, put

I need to allow PUT request on Tomcat, installed through XAMPP. I found various answer on web but no one works for me. 
I tried to add in my project web.xml this code:

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>allow</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
    <http-method>PUT</http-method>
</web-resource-collection>
<!-- no auth-constraint tag here -->
```

I also tried to modify the server Tomcat web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-     class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>listings</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>readonly</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

but every PUT still doesn't work. Tested on Postman the response status is 204 but the method isn't executed.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>allow</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
    <http-method>PUT</http-method>
</web-resource-collection>
<!-- no auth-constraint tag here -->
```

These restrict or "constrain" what methods can be executed.  Only add here what you don't want to allow.